# R Flexdashboard - add a break in the title

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am new to R markdown. My title for the dashboard is big. I want it to appear like this:

```
Uber data analysis 
(NYC, April 2014 - September 2014)
```

As of now, it comes out in one line like in the image below:

[image]

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, include the code to generate the output as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this isn't easier. A way to hack it is to use the author YAML input as the subtitle and use some css to rearrange the title. If you run the following Rmarkdown file, you should see the title now on two lines.

````
---
title: "Uber data analysis"
author: "(NYC, April 2014 - September 2014)"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

<style>

.navbar-brand {
  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navbar-author {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
</style>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Highlights
========================================

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```
````